# vue 3 как получить элемент со страницы

Tags: vue.js

vue 3 как получить элемент со страницы?
есть ли во vue 3 способ как получить элемент со страницы, по типу как в jquery $('') или как то по другому?

Comment: Не могли бы Вы рассказать зачем Вам это?

Comment: Возможно, v-model поможет. Хотелось бы подробнее узнать задачу.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, называется ["Template Refs"](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-template-refs.html). Только не совсем понятно, зачем вам это нужно, т.к. в большинстве случаев необходимость обратиться к DOM напрямую означает проблемы с архитектурой приложения.

Добавьте конкретики в вопрос нажатием кнопки "править" под ним, и я обновлю ответ в соответствии с вашим конкретным случаем.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector('<нужный вам компонент>')
```

Comment: Пожалуйста воздержитесь от "вредных" ответов. Вероятнее всего человеку совсем не нужен доступ к DOM.